# How do I resolve a 419 error from ui:auth?

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently started Laravel and started a tutorial on it. I installed my homestead box on Windows 10 using Virtualbox (had to make some [modifications](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#provider-specific-virtualbox) to get it working) and I'm now working with it for laravel. The tutorial i'm following is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE), and I was able to install the auth module using the new commands ( `composer require laravel/ui` and `php artisan ui:auth`). I followed the exact same steps to add a username, but I have been getting a 419 error. I haven't edited anything about the sessions, so Googling hasn't helped much. I can link some files if needed.

Changes in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php:

```php
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'], #added this line
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'], #added this line
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Changes in app/User.php:

```php
protected $fillable = [
        'name','username', 'email', 'password', #added username
    ];
```

Changes in database/migrations/create_users_table.php:

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('username')->unique(); #added this line
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Changes in resources/views/auth/register.blade.php:

```php
# added this whole div
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autocomplete="username" autofocus>

                                @error('username')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: 419 error occurs due to CSRF token verification failure, misconfigured cache, permissions, improper session settings, etc. Make sure you pass the `@csrf` from your blade

Comment: @TalhaF. Thanks for your help. I've tried both `@csrf` and `{{ csrf_field() }}`, but unfortunately neither make a difference. `@csrf` is there automatically.

Comment: You need to tell us what are you using to send your SPA requests to the backend ? axios, guzzle, ... then we could tell you how to include the csrf token into your request

Comment: I'm not using any, or at least i'm using whatever laravel has already installed.